# Vector image not "rendering" properly in document

Tags: graphics, pdf

[This PDF file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0wv2lxlmjxtx3i9/shaft.pdf?dl=0) was generated initially with Autodesk Inventor 2017, then **marks of text and arrows were added using Acrobat Reader 2015**. Inserting the file in a LaTeX document produces an undesired output, the file somewhat does not "render" properly.

## Desired Output

[image: Desired Output]

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{shaft.pdf}
\end{document}
```

## MWE Output

[image: MWE Output]

Note the arrows somehow dissapeared, I always use Inkscape for vector images, never had such a trouble. In this case, a colleague of mine generated the file, and I am wondering, **how come this happens?**, **is this the correct way to place PDF vector images?** (I always place them in a `figure` environment and never had a problem).

Comment: It depends how the arrows etc. were added. If they are annotations, they are probably stripped. Generally, Adobe don't let you do much in Reader that sticks unless the file is pre-enabled by a full version of one of their commercial applications.

Comment: @cfr Actually, according to my colleague, the full version of Acrobat was used, what I am most concerned is that I am a Linux user, and as you may guess, I don't have Acrobat running on my computer, but it still let's me see the arrows with another PDF viewer. Further: I used Inkscape to see the file, guess what?, the arrows are in there, I feel really confused, is LaTeX able to access the PDF image raw data?

Comment: That seems odd. Though, as I say, it may depend on how they were added: what kind of PDF object they are.

Comment: One try could be to open the PDF file in Gimp and export is as PDF (check all export options except `Apply layer mask`). Does it then render correctly in LaTeX output?

Comment: @TeXnician Thanks for your answer, however that would be completely against the desired: vector graphics. Like if I tell you to instead of doing a plot with matlab and export it in PDF, do it with excel and take a screenshot. Besides, the question is not about how to obtain a picture, is in regards of why is this happening, why is LaTeX doing this.

Comment: Okay, for the why you probably should analyze the type of PDF object the arrows are (as cfr stated) and for the correct way to place PDF vector images you are using it currently. My comment was just an approach to show, whether the arrows render in a raster graphic.

Comment: The arrows are also lost editing the PDF with Inkscape (and moreover discover that  is a bigger drawing). There are something odd in this PDF, may be that is the version 1.6 or something else, I don't have idea of the true problem, but is not (only) a LaTeX problem.

Comment: You can use `ps2pdf shaft.pdf shaft2.pdf` and include `shaft2.pdf`...

Comment: @Fran Thanks for answering, now I am more astonished, I used Inkscape as well, I notice the big black stroke box around the image, however the arrows are not lost for me there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, that the later in Adobe Reader added **arrows are annotations**. Annotations are -- apparently -- not displayed when you include a PDF file into LaTeX.

One solution is to **print the PDF file as a PDF file** with the following options.

[image]

1. Choose a PDF printer.
2. Make sure that you print the annotations as well (which is default on my system).
3. Make sure that the size is set to "fit" (I have the German version -- don't know the proper English term).

> You can include the resulting PDF as usual in LaTeX and the
>   annotations will be shown.