# Margin setup with geometry package

Tags: pdftex, geometry

I am trying to get left margin = 1.5inch (3.81 cm) and right-, top-, bottom-margin = 2.5cm each. For this, I tried the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{book}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[left = 1.5in, right = 2.5cm, top = 2.5cm, bottom = 2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
Some text
\end{document}
```

However, I am getting 4.4cm in the left margin, 4.4cm in the bottom margin and 3.3cm in the right margin. How to resolve this. Thanks in advance.

[image: page_margin]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you sure you're printing on A4 paper with output magnification/reduction set to 100%?

Comment: Are you sure that the printer hasn't scaled the document?

Comment: Yes , I have tried printing this in 2-3 different printers. The result is the same. I couldn't figure out the solution.

Comment: What compiler do you use?

Comment: I am using the default in TeXShop in Mac.

Comment: @Anstudent Texshop is a front-end. Do you compile it with `pdftex`, `luatex` or `xetex`?

Comment: I am using pdftex.

Comment: When I compile your document, I get the `Some text` indented. But on what you have show there is no indent. I would recommend updating your TeX distribution. I also recommend double-checking printing settings in your pdf viewer.

Comment: Show your log-file.

Comment: When you Print (Cmd-P) expand the information in that Print dialog box and make sure it isn't being scaled. also, how does it look on screen?

Comment: See point 3 of my answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359955. This addresses the `scaleing issue` the commenters are referring to.

Comment: Thanks to everyone here. I deleted all the printers and reinstalled a fresh one and the problem was solved. As pointed out here, it was in fact the scaling that was getting messed up.

Comment: @Anstudent Feel free to post that as an answer and mark your (own) answer as "accepted".

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, it was the scaling issue. I uninstalled all the printers and installed a fresh one and the problem is now solved.